# Создать ярлык на рабочем столе после запуска исполняемого файла

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Необходимо создать ярлык .exe файла на рабочем столе после запуска приложения. Однократно или с перезаписью все равно как. Директория расположения файла во время первого запуска может быть разной. Например C:\ или D:\ - не обязательно корень. Создавая ярлык, делать это автономно, без участия юзера. Имею ввиду без всплывающих вопросов о подтверждении той или иной операции с созданием ярлыка.

Честно, гуглил вопрос. Одно из решений было таковым. В проекте, добавить ссылку. В разделе COM поставить флаг напротив Windows Script Host Object Model.

Дальше мой процесс застопорился.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using IWshRuntimeLibrary;

public static void Create(string ShortcutPath, string TargetPath)
{
    WshShell wshShell = new WshShell(); //создаем объект wsh shell

    IWshShortcut Shortcut = (IWshShortcut)wshShell.
        CreateShortcut(ShortcutPath);

    Shortcut.TargetPath = TargetPath; //путь к целевому файлу

    Shortcut.Save();
}


Create(@"C:\test.lnk", @"C:\Windows\notepad.exe");
```

Comment: Как можно избавиться от жесткой привязки к исполняемому файлу? В Вашем примере (спасибо за пример!) запускается блокнот из папки винды, и далее создается ярлык в корне диска С. Возможно ли создавать ярлык уже в окружение пользователя из под которого запущена приложение? Пользователей много, и директория хранения\запуска приложения у всех разная. Это возможно?

Comment: @padawan Я при запуске примера не видел что бы запускался блокнот, вы уверены?

Comment: Путь до нужного файла определяете вы в своем коде, хоть в космос его укажите, к созданию ярлыка это не относится. Разделяйте задачи, а не мешайте отдельные вопросы в кашу. Создание ярлыка отдельная задача, а получение пути до файла это отдельная задача. И спасибо на данном ресурсе выражают по другому.